# Amazon S3 concatenate small files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, concatenation

Is there a way to concatenate small files which are less than 5MBs on Amazon S3.
Multi-Part Upload is not ok because of small files.

It's not a efficient solution to pull down all these files and do the concatenation.

So, can anybody tell me some APIs to do these?

Comment: Are the files already on S3? If not, can't you concatenate (or zip) before uploading?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Amazon S3 does not provide a concatenate function.** It is primarily an object storage service.

You will need some process that downloads the objects, combines them, then uploads them again. The most efficient way to do this would be to **download the objects in parallel**, to take full advantage of available bandwidth. However, that is more complex to code.

I would recommend doing the processing on "in the cloud" to avoid having to download the objects across the Internet. Doing it on **Amazon EC2 or AWS Lambda** would be more efficient and less costly.

Comment: Old comment, but this is not completely correct. You can have a 5MB garbage object sitting on S3 and do concatenation with it where part 1 = 5MB garbage object, part 2 = your file that you want to concatenate. Keep repeating this for each fragment and finally use the range copy to strip out the 5MB garbage.

Comment: @wwadge  Oooh! That is sinister and *very* cool! Using a [Upload Part - Copy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/mpUploadUploadPartCopy.html) to copy data from multiple files as if they were parts of the same file. Neat!

Comment: For the above Upload Part - Copy, it works provided your files are all >5MB (one of them can be less). You could treat them as a MultiPart Upload and just get S3 to concatenate them for you

Answer (score 8):

Based on @wwadge's comment I wrote a Python script.

It bypasses the 5MB limit by uploading a dummy-object slightly bigger than 5MB, then append each small file as if it was the last. In the end it strips out the dummy-part from the merged file.

```py
import boto3
import os

bucket_name = 'multipart-bucket'
merged_key = 'merged.json'
mini_file_0 = 'base_0.json'
mini_file_1 = 'base_1.json'
dummy_file = 'dummy_file'

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')

# we need to have a garbage/dummy file with size > 5MB
# so we create and upload this
# this key will also be the key of final merged file
with open(dummy_file, 'wb') as f:
    # slightly > 5MB
    f.seek(1024 * 5200) 
    f.write(b'0')

with open(dummy_file, 'rb') as f:
    s3_client.upload_fileobj(f, bucket_name, merged_key)

os.remove(dummy_file)


# get the number of bytes of the garbage/dummy-file
# needed to strip out these garbage/dummy bytes from the final merged file
bytes_garbage = s3_resource.Object(bucket_name, merged_key).content_length

# for each small file you want to concat
# when this loop have finished merged.json will contain 
# (merged.json + base_0.json + base_2.json)
for key_mini_file in ['base_0.json','base_1.json']: # include more files if you want

    # initiate multipart upload with merged.json object as target
    mpu = s3_client.create_multipart_upload(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=merged_key)
        
    part_responses = []
    # perform multipart copy where merged.json is the first part 
    # and the small file is the second part
    for n, copy_key in enumerate([merged_key, key_mini_file]):
        part_number = n + 1
        copy_response = s3_client.upload_part_copy(
            Bucket=bucket_name,
            CopySource={'Bucket': bucket_name, 'Key': copy_key},
            Key=merged_key,
            PartNumber=part_number,
            UploadId=mpu['UploadId']
        )

        part_responses.append(
            {'ETag':copy_response['CopyPartResult']['ETag'], 'PartNumber':part_number}
        )

    # complete the multipart upload
    # content of merged will now be merged.json + mini file
    response = s3_client.complete_multipart_upload(
        Bucket=bucket_name,
        Key=merged_key,
        MultipartUpload={'Parts': part_responses},
        UploadId=mpu['UploadId']
    )

# get the number of bytes from the final merged file
bytes_merged = s3_resource.Object(bucket_name, merged_key).content_length

# initiate a new multipart upload
mpu = s3_client.create_multipart_upload(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=merged_key)            
# do a single copy from the merged file specifying byte range where the 
# dummy/garbage bytes are excluded
response = s3_client.upload_part_copy(
    Bucket=bucket_name,
    CopySource={'Bucket': bucket_name, 'Key': merged_key},
    Key=merged_key,
    PartNumber=1,
    UploadId=mpu['UploadId'],
    CopySourceRange='bytes={}-{}'.format(bytes_garbage, bytes_merged-1)
)
# complete the multipart upload
# after this step the merged.json will contain (base_0.json + base_2.json)
response = s3_client.complete_multipart_upload(
    Bucket=bucket_name,
    Key=merged_key,
    MultipartUpload={'Parts': [
       {'ETag':response['CopyPartResult']['ETag'], 'PartNumber':1}
    ]},
    UploadId=mpu['UploadId']
)
```

If you already have a >5MB object that you want to add smaller parts too, then skip creating the dummy file and the last copy part with the byte-ranges. Also, I have no idea how this performs on a large number of very small files - in that case it might be better to download each file, merge them locally and then upload.

Comment: I can confirm that this does not perform as well on a large number of very small files. Not for my use case at least. My use case is for small xml files. A lambda that downloads, merges, Gzips and uploads is faster.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit:** Didn't see the 5MB requirement. This method will not work because of this requirement.

From https://ruby.awsblog.com/post/Tx2JE2CXGQGQ6A4/Efficient-Amazon-S3-Object-Concatenation-Using-the-AWS-SDK-for-Ruby:

> While it is possible to download and re-upload the data to S3 through
>   an EC2 instance, a more efficient approach would be to instruct S3 to
>   make an internal copy using the new copy_part API operation that was
>   introduced into the SDK for Ruby in version 1.10.0.

Code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'aws-sdk'

s3 = AWS::S3.new()
mybucket = s3.buckets['my-multipart']

# First, let's start the Multipart Upload
obj_aggregate = mybucket.objects['aggregate'].multipart_upload

# Then we will copy into the Multipart Upload all of the objects in a certain S3 directory.
mybucket.objects.with_prefix('parts/').each do |source_object|

  # Skip the directory object
  unless (source_object.key == 'parts/')
    # Note that this section is thread-safe and could greatly benefit from parallel execution.
    obj_aggregate.copy_part(source_object.bucket.name + '/' + source_object.key)
  end

end

obj_completed = obj_aggregate.complete()

# Generate a signed URL to enable a trusted browser to access the new object without authenticating.
puts obj_completed.url_for(:read)
```

Limitations (among others)

- With the exception of the last part, there is a 5 MB minimum part size.
- The completed Multipart Upload object is limited to a 5 TB maximum size.