How to write a very large Spark dataframe to a single csv file into AWS S3?
I have a very large Spark DataFrame that I need to write as a single CSV file into an AWS S3 bucket (I use pySpark).
I cannot use the standard csv_df.coalesce(1).write.csv() approach as the file is too large to be processed by one node only (insufficient memory).
I was unable to find any info on S3 having some kind of append mode.
How to achieve this? I would prefer some kind of parallelized write to S3 to speed things up, if possible.

are you working with databricks or hadoop? What is the file system you are working with?

S3 is an object store; no append. It would be possible to do this with some explicit code (either the hadoop multipart API, or AWS SDK COPY operation); AFAIK nobody has done this -or at least shared their work

see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32448416/amazon-s3-concatenate-small-files

Perhaps use toLocalIterator. But that would be inherently not parallel though, because as @stevel says it hasn't been done.

I have no idea how performant this solution is, but it does allow for parallelizing writing a CSV to S3.
import boto3
import csv
from io import StringIO
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import Row
from typing import Iterator


def func(partition_num: int, itr: Iterator[Row]):
    global upload_id
    global bucket_name
    global key
    partition_num += 1
    with StringIO() as buffer:
        for i, row in enumerate(itr):
            row = row.asDict()
            if not i:
                writer = csv.DictWriter(buffer, row.keys(), lineterminator="\n")
                if partition_num == 1:
                    writer.writeheader()
            writer.writerow(row)
        buffer.truncate(buffer.tell() - 1)  # Remove extra newline

        # Unfortunatly, s3_client isn't pickleable, 
        # so we have to create a new one for each partition.
        s3_client = boto3.client("s3")
        etag = s3_client.upload_part(
            Bucket=bucket_name,
            Key=key,
            PartNumber=partition_num,
            UploadId=upload_id,
            Body=buffer.getvalue().encode("utf-8"),
        )["ETag"]

        yield {"PartNumber": partition_num, "ETag": etag}

bucket_name = "BUCKET"
key = "myfile.csv"
s3_client = boto3.client("s3")
upload_id = s3_client.create_multipart_upload(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=key)["UploadId"]

spark: SparkSession = (
    SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").appName("MyApp").getOrCreate()
)
df = df  # Insert your dataframe

try:
    # Use a better method of partitioning than this,
    # but keep in mind they must all at least be 5mb.
    parts = df.rdd.coalesce(4).mapPartitionsWithIndex(func).collect()
except:
    s3_client.abort_multipart_upload(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=key, UploadId=upload_id)
    raise

s3_client.complete_multipart_upload(
    Bucket=bucket_name, Key=key, UploadId=upload_id, MultipartUpload={"Parts": parts}
)

